# Why'd I get this message in Sea Of Thieves?

Tags: sea-of-thieves

I was pulling up to Marauder's Arch to do a Gold Hunter mission when I got this message on my screen.

> The world is changing, new dangers there be
>
> Between boundless sky and treacherous sea
>
> On rolling waves with sails unfolded
>
> Ships come to plunder this new world

Why did I get this and does it change anything? Nothing happened after this but awhile before I ran into the Megalondon. Don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. This message appears when there are too few players on a server. The game will then merge two servers together to make sure you're never the only player on a server.

Comment: Be sure to mark your answer as the answer to the question, good find by the way! :)

Comment: There is a 2 day wait before I could, thanks for the reminder though. Would have completely forgotten!